# Is there a way to get amplify frontend to reflect dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

So I have a web application that was built with amplify and it's connected to a dynamodb table. Every time my api is hit, a lambda function writes to the dynamodb table. All the changes are seen both on dynamodb and amplify but on the frontend of the website (react.js) it's still showing the old data. If i make the change directly in the amplify console it shows on the frontend but not when changes are made to the actual dynamodb table. Is there a way to get amplify to recognize these changes without making them in the amplify console?

I tried to update my dynamodb table with a lambda function, the data is updated in dynamodb and shows the correct data in amplify console, but on the frontend it still shows the old data, unless I make a direct change in the amplify console.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that GraphQL is responsible for updating your frontend. When you make a change directly to DynamoDB it's not updated on your frontend as you don't make the change via GraphQL.

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/getting-started/q/platform/js/